# how to read an excel file which has no path

Tags: c#, process

I've been using this code to read an excel file and it works fine when i am trying to read saved excel files

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\temp\test.xls;" +   @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";    

using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
   connection.Open();
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", 
   connection); 
   using(OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while(dr.Read())
      {
         var row1Col0 = dr[0];
         Console.WriteLine(row1Col0);
      }
    }
}
```

theres and application which opens an excel file which updates data every second and here is the pic of the app

here you can see the excel file being opened in the taskbar.when i used the process code to read the path of the excel file using this code i get no data as the file located in that path is empty

Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

```
        foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
        {
            if (theprocess.ProcessName == "EXCEL")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
                string fullPath = theprocess.MainModule.FileName;
                //fullpath = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\EXCEL.EXE

            }
        }
```

the application might be using the instance of ms excel directly.is there any alternative step to read this excel file by the process id directly instead of the path?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you think about the fact that the application that updates the excel file also locks it?

Comment: it is'nt locked.it updates for each and every second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Processes` are not meant to be used this way. You can start, stop and kill a `Process`, but there is no way to gain access to it's memory and read a file (actually, any stream of data) with it. I also don't think that there is a way to access the path of the opened file by the `Process` class.

However, using the [Office Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/default.aspx) COM API, you can get the current file, including it's path with [Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.fullname.aspx).

Be advised, that this solution works only if one instance of Excel is opened.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application MyExcelApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
string FullPath = MyExceAppl.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;
```

Comment: i guess you did not get my question.the process does not have a path to be read. there is no file in the path to read.its just a process which used ms excel to open without any source path.

Comment: Unless MS Excel moves the file while updating it, it should be right there :) Is the file there in Windows Explorer?

Comment: yes C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Excel.exe is the path which is being shown. but when i try to open that file a new excel sheet is being opened . thus it concludes that the file is being opened without a path .. :)